# Deployment matrix for occupancy with multiple gaps between several deployment time spans per deployment

Tags: r, wildlife-ecology

I have a deployment table for camera traps. At each placement (place_id), camera traps were deployed several times over several years and each deployment time frame has a deployment_id. My table `data` looks like this:

```
place_id  deployment_id latitude  longitude  start_date            end_date
A1        A1_D1         40.83815  -8.23506   2019-09-06 10:36:00   2019-10-14 09:36:00
A1        A1_D2         40.83815  -8.23506   2019-10-20 09:42:00   2019-11-05 19:02:00
A1        A1_D3         40.83815  -8.23506   2020-01-01 19:03:00   2020-02-20 08:51:00
A2        A2_D1         40.83254  -8.22986   2019-05-06 19:02:00   2019-06-10 17:28:00
A2        A2_D2         40.83254  -8.22986   2019-04-17 07:42:00   2019-05-06 18:58:00
A3        A3_D1         40.83270  -8.22940   2019-01-09 15:58:00   2019-02-06 08:03:00
```

I want to generate a deployment matrix for camera traps for occupancy analyses. The deployment matrix should consist of a place_id in each row and a column for each day. The values are:

- `NA` for each day, if the camera at the given place and day was not active
- `1` for each day if the camera was activated

Something like this:

```
    01-01-2019  01-02-2019  01-03-2019  01-04-2019 01-05-2019    .............
A1  NA          NA          1           1          1             .............
A2  NA          NA          NA          NA         NA            .............
A3  1           1           1           1          NA            .............
A4  NA          NA          NA          1          1             .............
```

The package camtrapR can create such a table with the function `cameraOperation()`, it looks like that:

```
cameraOperation(CTtable      = data,
                stationCol   = "place_id",
                setupCol     = "start_date",
                retrievalCol = "end_date",
                hasProblems  = FALSE, 
                dateFormat   = "ymd",
                writecsv     = FALSE)
```

However, this code needs an input table (my table `data`) which has **only one row per place_id**, which brings up my problem. How can I solve that / is there another possibility to create the deployment matrix?

I'm aware that camera operability (`cameraOperation()`) can handle single gaps in camtrap data with the "hasproblems" argument but I am yet to make it correctly handle multiple gaps, i.e. multiple sets of "ProblemX_from and ProblemX_to" columns.

Comment: What output do you want for your multiple deployments? Do you want to merge them over place_id? Then create the table for unique deployment ids and then do a grouped operation based on the first part of the deployment id (which is the place id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the help for `cameraOperation` I'm a bit confused about the options and terminology. But I think you only ever have one camera at each place at any time, so one way may be to treat the deployment as the unique event, and then aggregate the matrix.

First compute the table using `deployment_id` as `stationCol`:

```
ctab = cameraOperation(
    CTtable      = data,
    stationCol   = "deployment_id",
    setupCol     = "start_date",
    retrievalCol = "end_date",
    hasProblems  = FALSE,
    dateFormat   = "ymd",
    writecsv     = FALSE)
```

Then extract the `place_id` from the matrix row names - this subs the underscore and anything after it with an empty string leaving the first part only - the place ID:

```
place = gsub("_.*","",rownames(ctab))
```

Then `rowsums` has a handy group option, so you sum the rows based on the place id:

```
ctabtotals = rowsum(ctab, place, na.rm=TRUE, reorder=FALSE)
```

Which gives you something like this:

```
> ctabtotals[,1:5]
   2019-01-09 2019-01-10 2019-01-11 2019-01-12 2019-01-13
A1        0.0          0          0          0          0
A2        0.0          0          0          0          0
A3        0.5          1          1          1          1
```

Which you can plot to show for example the three deployments of A1:

```
plot(ctabtotals[1,],type="l")
```

[image]

Note I couldn't get it to work with date-times so I converted your data to dates using `as.Date`. I think the docs say if you use times you can get fractional counts in the matrix for partial days coverages.

If you want NA for days with no cameras you'll have to compute that separately since `rowsum` will either treat `NA` as `NA` and you get an `NA` sum for anything with an `NA` in it, or it'll treat it as zero even if you sum only `NA` values...

Comment: yes, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot my Spacedman, you saved my day :D